# Does The Walking Dead Season 2 Playstation Plus offering include all episodes?

Tags: playstation-plus

I do not have a Playstation 4 yet so I cannot test, but I am purchasing all the games offered on my PS Plus membership for PS4. I was wondering though, it is described that in this month the are offering The Walking Dead Season 2. So I suppose this means that they are including all the episodes of Season 2. Right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, they include all episodes. I downloaded the game and it has all episodes.